# Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : No response received

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation

Im using [geolocated package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-geolocated)

and i always see this error in console despite i allowed the location permission

```
Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : No response received.
```

it only happens in chrome and on every website (google map)

it sometimes shows up at fire fox if i refresh the page repeatedly